# Как распознать ввод с разных устройств ввода

Tags: c#, usb

Есть 2 считывателя магнитных карт usb. В диспетчере устройств определяются как устройства ввода. Собственно, работают как клавиатуры, подносишь карту, он отправляет в систему набор цифр будто бы их вводили с клавиатуры.
Нужно на компьютере с ПО, к которому подключено 2 считывателя, распознать, с какого именно считывателя идет сигнал, программно на шарпе.

Comment: нагуглил, работает. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.